# PHP foreach is stopping after first iteration

Tags: php, file, foreach

I have form where I have three inputs for files. With code below, I try to move files from TMP localisation to ./uploads with some random hash and name of file.

I have issue with `foreach` because it is stopping, after first iteration and saving file to uploads directory. I do not know why it is not happening for other two elements in table. Whole function below, it is a little mess, but I hope it is understandable.

```
function saveFile(){
global $patchFile;


$fileArray = [ $_FILES['file_one']['name'], $_FILES['file_two']['name'], $_FILES['file_three']['name'] ];
$tmpArray = [ $_FILES['file_one']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file_two']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file_three']['tmp_name'] ];

$multiArray = 
[
    [$_FILES['file_one']['name'], $_FILES['file_one']['tmp_name']],
    [$_FILES['file_two']['name'], $_FILES['file_two']['tmp_name']],
    [$_FILES['file_three']['name'], $_FILES['file_three']['tmp_name']]
];

foreach ($multiArray as $key) 
{
    echo "<br />Key: ".$key[0]."\n";
    echo "Key_tmp: ".$key[1]."\n";


    $randomString = generateRandomString();
    $patchFile = './uploads/'.$randomString.$key[0];

    echo "<br />Check patchFile: $patchFile";

    if(is_uploaded_file($key[1]))
    {
        echo "<br />Begin uploading to directory...<br />";
        if(!move_uploaded_file($key[1], $patchFile))
        {
          echo 'Problem: Nie udało się skopiować pliku do katalogu.';
            return false;  
        }
        else {
            echo "File was saved in uploads directory";
            return true;
        }   
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Uploading to directory... FAILED!";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: when you `return` something from a loop, the loop is always broken

Comment: You should make an answer from this comment;) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `return` something from a loop, the loop is always broken.

As per [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php):

> If called from within a function, the `return` statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call.